# Webpage desconfiguring on https access

Tags: html, css, ssl, https

I have set my website to force https access via htaccess.
The main [site](https://azaz.com.br) is working normal
But the [blog](http://azaz.com.br/blog) (that is located at one of the main site folder's azaz.com.br/blog) is desconfiguring only on HTTPS.

I dont know why and how to solve this, so I appreciate any help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your `<head>`, you are getting your files using `http://` not `https://`. According to the developer tools on Google Chrome it says:

`Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Google and most browser don't like this because they think that you are getting files from an unsafe file server.